# Cannot get append() working in the right way

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem with append I think, to be honest I do not really know where my problem is in the code, but I just can not make it work. First I will show you my code and then I will try my best to explain what my problem is.

```
$('.dynamic').append('<div class="clipboardContent"></div>').html(window[recentPerson].fullname + '<br><span style="color:lightgray; font-size:10pt">' + window[recentPerson].mail + '</span>');
$('.dynamic').append('<div class="clipboardContent">HI</div>');
```

So what you can see here are two pieces of code. The first one is the one that I want to work but does not. The second one is more simple but does work. My problem is that if I click on a button it sould create a div in the class clipboardContent with some text in it (this still works), but if I click again It doesn't add a new one (But the second code does). I hope someone can explain to my why the first code only works one time.

PS. If you have some other questions or you need more code / explanation of my problem feel free to let me know.

Comment: Hint: `html()` applies to `.dynamic`, not to the new `<div>` you just appended.

Comment: .html() will reset what you append before,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue you have is that the `append()` method returns the element originally selected. In your case this is the `.dynamic` element. After appending you are setting the `html()` of `.dynamic` which then overwrites the `div` you added in the `append()`.

To do what you require you can create the `div` element separately before appending:

```
$('<div />', {
    class: 'clipboardContent',
    html: window[recentPerson].fullname + '<br><span style="color: lightgray; font-size: 10pt">' + window[recentPerson].mail + '</span>'
}).appendTo('.dynamic');
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/e97u4m13/)

Or you could keep your current method and include the HTML in the string being appended:

```
$('.dynamic').append('<div class="clipboardContent">' + window[recentPerson].fullname + '<br><span style="color:lightgray; font-size:10pt">' + window[recentPerson].mail + '</span></div>');
```

Also, as a side-note, you should look to using CSS classes on your elements over inline `style` attributes. This way you can make all styling changes in a single place, instead of having to amend your JS files to affect style rules.

Comment: I second what Rory said, the simpler method will work. 

Just add the content of window[recentPerson] to the append call. Using .html() will override the content of the existing clipboardContent div.

Comment: Thank you :D I will stick with the 2 second method because I understand that one better

Comment: No problem, glad to help. Here's an explanation of how the first example is working: http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.append()`, not `.html()` because it will overwrite previous content added by `.append()`

```
$(".dynamic").append('<div class="clipboardContent">YOUR_CONTENT</div>');
```